# Are mazes allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

While mazes **are** a type of puzzle, I was wondering what the policy was on them.

There's also a [mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes) tag. This also brings me to a conclusion we accept them?

They're definitely fully defined, there's *usually* only one answer so it isn't too broad or opinionated, but they **can be used over and over again**.

What if it has a creative twist on it to make it on topic (that is, if it is indeed off topic)?

Comment: [Personally,](http://puzzle.cisra.com.au/2013/2B-On-the-Right-Track.pdf) [I think that](http://puzzle.cisra.com.au/2012/1D-Labyrinth.pdf) [creative mazes](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/ub/sums/puzzlehunt/2011/puzzles/A5S3_Test_Chamber.pdf) [are fair game.](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~mums/puzzlehunt/2012/puzzles/2.4_Cat_Walk.pdf)

Comment: @Sp3000 That's one opinion :D I need others to come and tell me what they think too.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. They're a kind of puzzle, so I can't see why they wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

A maze is on topic, provided a maze does indeed amaze!

Answer (score 3):

Mazes are clearly mass-producible puzzles. There are programs that generate mazes for you at the click of a button. There is no end to how many mazes one can post.

Unless the maze has a clearly new and original mechanic, I don't see what it adds to the site.

(Discussion about mazes, generation, and strategy is fine.)